# AWS Fargate and its memory management

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

From *AWS* documentation I can see that `CPU` and `Memory` properties are required in the [AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ecs-taskdefinition.html) for *Fargate* but not in the [ContainerDefinition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ecs-taskdefinition-containerdefinitions.html) within the resource if *Fargate* is used.

How does this exactly work?  If I do not specify it in the `ContainerDefinition` it will use as much resources the Task have available?  If there is only one container within the task... does it make any sense defining those values?  If they are required, it seems pretty redundant and verbose to me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When a container has no specified limits in a `TaskDefinition`, the container will use all the available resources for the task, which are mandatory for a `Fargate` task.

This means that there is no need to define them if there is only one container in the `TaskDefinition`.  They can be specified though they are redundant (if equal to those of the task itself) or even harmful (if they are lower than the amount given to the task).

In case more than once container belongs to the same task, `Fargate` will distribute evenly the resources among all the containers.  This may (or not) be a desired behaviour.

Comment: What does "distribute evenly" mean? If you have .5 cpu and 1G memory, are you saying each container gets .25 cpu and .5G memory? I don't think this is how it works.

Comment: I just went through my mailbox to find the AWS support engineers answer to this, and it is how it works unless it has changed in the last two years.  I remember locally testing this with some Java workload and having my task failing.

Comment: You have a source on that? After some experimentation, I am relatively sure they are not "distributed evenly", but just shared, as in - within one task, the containers have access to the same memory pool and CPU allotment.

Answer (score 12):

When you register a task definition, you can specify the total cpu and memory used for the task. This is separate from the cpu and memory values at the container definition level.

If using the Fargate launch type, these task definition fields are required and there are specific values for both cpu and memory that are supported. This will be a hard limit of CPU/Memory to present to the task. For example, if your task is configured to use 1 vCPU and 2 GB of memory, so at the moment the memory limit is 2 GB. If at any moment the task memory utilization exceed the 2 GB, the task will terminate with OutOfMemory error.

Task size: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html#task_size

You can also specify cpu and memory resource on the container level. This will be the amount of resources to present to the container (a Task can have multiple containers). If your container attempts to exceed the resource specified here, the container is killed. These fields are optional for tasks using the Fargate launch type, and the only requirement is that the total amount of cpu and memory reserved for all containers within a task be lower than the task-level cpu and memory value, if one is specified.

On a container level, the Docker daemon reserves a minimum of 4 MiB of memory for a container, so you should not specify fewer than 4 MiB of memory for your containers.

Standard Container Definition Parameters: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html#standard_container_definition_params